# Use of "sx" prop in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sx

What is the significance of `sx` prop here when you can write the styling outside it too. Here I noticed that whether I use the `px` tag inside `sx` or outside it, the result is the same. So, what is the importance of the `sx` prop here?

```
<Typography fontSize={12} mb={1} px={1} sx={{color:"#999",backgroundColor:"#000",display: "inline",borderRadius: 1}}>
 Only zip type files are allowed
</Typography>
```

Comment: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/